# select query in sqlite doesn't return anything

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using the Firefox sqlite manager addon and I have a database table named - drinktable. I need to extract all the columns where the title matches a certain string. This is the query I am running right now  -

**`SELECT * FROM drinktable where title = 'First Drink';`**

But it won't return anything. It just shows the 4 columns in the database, but nothing in those columns. Can someone please tell me why ?

Comment: Could it be because no row in `first` contains `'First Drink'` in the `drinktable` column?

Comment: I made a typo while typing the question. Fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a database table named - drinktable.

One thing in your question. Your table name is `drinktable` and you are querying against `first`, is it a typo. In SQL Select statement you specify table name after from and column name in where clause

```
SELECT * FROM drinktable where first =  'First Drink';

Select * from <TableName> where <ColumnName> = 'Value to compare';
```

If your table name is first and column name is drinktable then chances are that there are now row(s) with column `drinktable` set to 'First Drink'. You might have spaces or some other characters. Try

```
SELECT * FROM first where drinktable like  '%First Drink%';
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your edited question, chances are you have spaces or some other characters, try:

```
SELECT * FROM drinktable where title like '%First Drink%';
```

Comment: I made a typo while typing the question. Fixed that.